# Changing page title of submit a new story page in pligg

Tags: content-management

I have installed latest version of pligg on my local server.

It's running fine.

Currently when i click on submit a new story it displays 'Submit a New Story, Step 2 of 3' as title. I want to edit this title. I am confused where should i make the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Admin-> Modules -> Install: Admin Modify Language then go to Admin Modify Language search for 'Submit a New Story' now you can edit and save.